# Identifying two BIONICLE parts, white and dark grey curved shell

Tags: part-identification, bionicle

What are these two BIONICLE pieces?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are Bionicle parts, specifically the back spine of the [8588-1 Rahkshi Kurahk](http://brickset.com/sets/8588-1/Rahkshi-Kurahk).

The individual parts are:

- http://brickset.com/parts/design-44140
- http://brickset.com/parts/design-44139

Answer (score 2):

Adding to zovits' answer, you also appear to have a [Part 44136](http://brickset.com/parts/design-44136) attached to the Part 44139.